# No files found loading Docker image

Tags: docker

I'm trying to load a Docker image into an environment without internet connection (`nginx:stable-alpine`).

Once I've downloaded the image with `pull` on a computer with internet connection, I use the `save` command:

```
docker image save --output docker-image-nginx.tar nginx:stable-alpine
```

Then I copy it to the environment without internet connection, and load it:

```
docker image load --input docker-image-nginx.tar
```

The image gets loaded and can be seen with `docker image ls`:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
nginx               stable-alpine       8c1bfa967ebf        4 weeks ago         21.5MB
```

But when I create a container with the `run` command:

```
docker run --name nginx -p 8080:80 nginx:stable-alpine
```

I get this error:

> /docker-entrypoint.sh: No files found in /docker-entrypoint.d/, skipping configuration

The container can be created with the same command on the computer with internet connection.

What's wrong in the process of saving and loading the image?

Answer (score 0):

What about trying to save a docker container instead an image?
For example:

**In your host with internet**

```
docker run --name mynginx -p 8080:80 nginx:stable-alpine
docker save mynginx > mynginx.tar
```

**In your host without internet**

```
docker load < mynginx.tar
```

Comment: I saved a container with `export`. Same problem there. I bypassed it running the container with `--privileged`, although would rather not use it.